# How to enumerate what languages/cultures resources are available in a WinRT App?

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I am porting an existing app to the 'WinRT' platform. This app searches for satellite resource DLLs in order to determine what languages have been localized.

Is there an equivalent mechanism by which I can enumerate languages with available resources in my WinRT application?

**Edit**

Still looking for how to do this, but in the meantime, I have hope that these articles will help me understand WinRT resources better:

http://www.silverlightrecipes.com/2012/03/building-global-windows-8-metro-xaml.html
http://www.silverlightrecipes.com/2012/04/building-global-windows-8-metro-xaml.html
http://www.silverlightrecipes.com/2012/04/pri-files-deep-dive-building-global.html

Answer (score 1):

You can try Windows.Globalization.ApplicationLanguages.Languages

Comment: Thanks - that isn't it, but the documentation for that property led me to ApplicationLanguages.ManifestLanguages, which I think is what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I came up with for rummaging in for all the values of a resource string, indexed by the language of the resource string:

In my case, the 'resourceKey' was a string like this:

```
string resourceKey = "Namespace/Resources/thekeyhere";
```

You can retrieve all the keys in a ResourceMap if you want to check this.

```
    private static Dictionary<string, string> GetResourceValuesByLanguage(string resourceKey)
    {
        var languages = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        var markerResource = ResourceManager.Current.MainResourceMap[resourceKey];
        var candidates = markerResource.Candidates;

        foreach (var c in candidates)
        {
            var lq = c.Qualifiers.FirstOrDefault(q => q.QualifierName == "Language");
            if (lq != null)
                languages[lq.QualifierValue] = c.ValueAsString;
        }
        return languages;
    }
```